# uninstall sublime text 3 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, uninstallation, sublimetext3

As the sublime text 3 beta has been released and opened to the public I decided to upgrade to it. Turns out that most of the plugins I generally use are not ready to use yet and it has slowed me down. I wanted to uninstall it and resume using sublime text, but haven't find any method of doing so apart from the revert, which would just reset the version 3.

I am waiting on any suggestions.

**EDIT**
I forgot to add that my sublime text 2 was not uninstalled so they both run concurrently only now whenever I try to open sublime text 2 it is shut down automatically after few seconds.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### Option 1

If you installed sublime-text-3 with apt-get, based on this article:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/sublime-text-3-ubuntu-ppa-now-available.html

With these lines:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

You could remove your installation:

```
sudo apt-get remove sublime-text-installer
```

#### Option 2

If you installed Sublime Text 3 from a .deb package which was downloaded directly from Sublime Text page: http://www.sublimetext.com/3

And you have used this command for installation

```
sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-3047_amd64.deb
```

Or you just double clicked on it and Ubuntu Software Center installed it...

So, in this case:

```
sudo dpkg -r sublime-text
```

But you have to reinstall Sublime Text 2 in each case... Your configurations are in different folders, so your previous settings which belongs to Sublime Text 2, will be still there.

Comment: I did try that, however I keep getting an error message saying that the package cannot be found... Any other ideas?

Comment: Answer updated, hope you can use something from it. Let me know what happened.

Comment: Any Ideas how I know in which way I installed this? I saw my folder /etc/apt/sources.list.d and I saw that I have there the ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3 but also I have the folder in the /opt where sublime is. may be the ppa installed there? or the .deb?

Comment: In my case I had to use snap: 
~ snap remove sublime-text

Answer (score 5):

To remove SUBLIME TEXT from your machine:

Go To Terminal and type:

```
sudo apt remove sublime-text
```

this worked for me....

Answer (score 3):

Base on answer by szine

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

At some point you’d want to be able to call Sublime Text from the Terminal by just typing “sublime”. To do that, we’ll just create a symbolic link in “/usr/bin” like thus:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use this command, it helped me 
`sudo apt-get remove sublime-text && sudo apt-get autoremove`

Answer (score 2):

Very simple `sudo apt remove sublime-text` or `sudo snap remove sublime-text` from command line might work. At least they worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me, had sublime-text persist even after apt removal, snap removal was the solution

Answer (score 1):

I was getting an error after error, so I navigated to `$: /usr/local/bin`, and I listed all. I figured out that I had already subl and sublime. I deleted both using "rm file_to_delete". Then I used Homebrew to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

for Ubuntu just open Terminal and write

> sudo apt remove sublime-text

Comment: Isn't this the same as [this answer from three years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54832365/354577)?